# Trying to capture one thing or another specific word with a regex

Tags: regex

Trying to capture the following with a regex:

```
test/thing_test.exs
test/ok_test.exs
file.yml
test/ok2_test.yml
```

I've tried the following:

`test\/.*\.exs$|file\.yml`

But that doesn't work. Trying to figure out how to capture each of these with a regex.

Comment: What strings should not match? From what you've specified, `.*` will match all of your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
^(?:test\/)?[^\s\/]+\.(?:yml|exs)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:test\/)?` Optionally match `test/`
- `[^\s\/]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or `/`
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?:yml|exs)` Match either `yml` or `exs`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QGLTIC/1).

Answer (score 1):

Your question was very vague so I'm making use of the information I could interpret. What I understand is that you want a regex that matches a filename ending in `exs` or `yml`. This could be a file in the current directory or it could be present in the `test` directory. If this understanding of mine is correct, then the following regex should help you in achieving this:

```
/^(test\/)?.*\.(yml|exs)$/
```